# NoMethodError in Posts#index undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and am trying to build a blog app where only signed in users can see the username of the person who created a post, however I keep getting this error NoMethodError in Posts#index  undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

[screenshot of error in localhost:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpNAe.png)

Here is my routes.rb

````
```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  devise_for :users
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in         https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"

  root "posts#index"


resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :index]

get "/posts/new.html.erb", to: "posts#create", as: "create"
get "/posts/new.html.erb", to: "posts#new", as: "new"
end

```
````

here is my posts_controller.rb

````
    class PostsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create 
        
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
        @post.user = current_user

        respond_to do |format|
        if @post.save
            
            format.html { redirect_to user_post_path(current_user, @post), notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
            
          else
            
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
    end

    def index 
        @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc)
        
    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
    end
    

    end
    ```


here is my post.rb model


    ```
    class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    end
    ```

here is my user.rb model


    ```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

   
         
      has_many :posts


      validates :username, presence: true
      validates :email, presence: true
      validates :password, presence: true

    end




  
    ``



here is my schema




    ```
    ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_11_14_173843) do
      create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
   end

    create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

    end
 
    ```
here is my AddNameToUsers migration


    ```
    class AddNameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
      def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string
    end
    end

    ```

Here is my AddUserIdToPosts migration

    
    ```
    class AddUserIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
   def change
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
    
    end
     end
    ```


Here is my CreatePosts Migration



     ```
    class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
    def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      
      t.timestamps
    end
    end
    end

    ```
````

Comment: please share the view too

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working, for the link_to error, I simply needed to remove the only: function in my routes.rb to only say resources :posts and for the username error I referenced a user in my createPosts migration and then cleared the Posts and Users in the rails console and started over from signing up to making a post to viewing all posts to seeing a single post

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the post object which is raising the Exception.

It looks like there is a `Post` object which doesnt have a user associated with it. So `post.user` returns nil and when `username` method is called on the nil object an Exception is raised as it is not defined on `nil`.

You may check in the rails console which post doesnt have a user associated with it and based on your requirements either correct such objects or remove the objects from being displayed in index or just do not show a username for posts if it is not present.